# Reading json file format from Twitter with truncated text output

Tags: python, json, twitter

I have a json file from twitter, but when I read this file with my code, I received truncated text show below. Can you help to show full line?

```
import re
import json
import pandas as pd

tweets_data_path = 'data/enem2.txt'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")

for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

tweets = pd.DataFrame()
tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)
print(tweets['text'])
```

Output:

```
[delermando@neublis twitter]$ python app/read_data.py
                                                 text
0   APOSTILA IMPRESSA ENEM 2015 !!\nPeça Já a Sua ...
1                            To só pelo enem ahsuhshs
2   APOSTILA IMPRESSA ENEM 2015 !!\nPeça Já a Sua ...
3   RT @brianejeqetuj: http://t.co/9xWg3dJGZj #Ene...
4   APOSTILA IMPRESSA ENEM 2015 !!\nPeça Já a Sua ...
5   Vou começar a fazer o pre-enem semana que vem,...
6                                     Corta oro ENEM!
7   Escolhi espanhol pro Enem e seila,sou pessima tnm
8   @Itsmelss siiiim , vou estudar de segunda a sá...
9   APOSTILA IMPRESSA ENEM 2015 !!\nPeça Já a Sua ...
```

Comment: You will need to be more specific with the exact format that you are expecting.

Comment: I expect a full line, see the line #5, the full text is: Vou começar a fazer o pre-enem semana que vem, nem acredito nisso